# Slow people picker issue in large organisations.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, people-picker, people-search

1. What is recommended time for people picker in large org.
   E.g Users : 10000+, multiple forests/domains at different locations.
   Our current time is 3-10 secs depends on location and domain.
2. What is correct format for peoplepicker-searchadforests value.
   Coz our email address are fname.lname@domain1.com or ff.ll@do2.com
   But when see FDQN its : main.sub.domain1.com or main2.sub2.in1.do2.com

I have tried both domain:domain1 and domain:main.sub.domain1.com
Both works fine, but which is correct format and will this affect speed ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with AD user name if possible, and it appears in less than seconed. 
If it is not handy to get username, then i use full email address and hit ente . i dont click on search this person or any button. i just type AD user name ( first choice), or AD Email address and hit enter.. hope this way you will find better. please let me know, if it was better. thakns

Comment: We have asked users to use email address and validate but it takes 5-6 secs.Is it that normal time?